# Extract Page 1 Header from Word Doc

Tags: python, text, ms-word, python-docx, text-parsing

I'm trying to extract multiple lines of text from the page 1 Header of an MS Word Document (.docx). I'm using python.docx but can't determine how specific I need to get in order to get only the 1st page header.

Code is currently:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document("path.docx")
section = document.sections[0]
header = section.header
print(header.paragraphs[0].text)
```

With the output: "Name of File; Smith; Page"

Screenshots linked for the content I'm referring to with Headers versus Running Header. I want the Header, I don't care about the Running Header:
[Header 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9EQH.png)
[Running Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYOuq.png)

Any help appreciated! I've looked at the documentation for headers in general (https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/hdrftr.html) but it does not go into specifics for dealing with the Different First Page Header feature of MS Word.

Comment: In Word, each section has three headers and three footers. They are not by page but there is the primary  (odd-page) header, the even-page header, and the first-page header. There is no Sections(0), the number starts with 1. The header on the first page will be either the first-page header of Section 1 or the primary header of Section 1.

Answer (score 0):

### In Word, each section has three headers and three footers.

They are not by page but there is the primary  (odd-page) header, the even-page header, and the first-page header.

There is no Sections(0), the number starts with 1. Every document has at least one section. Here is [my web page on sections](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm) if you need more about them and headers and footers.

The header on the first page will be either the first-page header of Section 1 or the primary header of Section 1. The code for the primary is `Activedocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text`; that for the first-page is `Activedocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text`.